# Bootstrap datepicker's view is not updating when trying to setDate from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for choosing dates multiple times.
I am trying to do like, if user select date of first datepicker then second datepicker should also get selected automatically.

I got success to do so using...

```
$('#firstDatePicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {
        if (e.date) {
            $("#secondDatePicker").datepicker("update", e.date);
            console.log(e.date,'changed');
        }
    });
```

This is working properly. But problem is, when I am sending data from another page to this page with the help of cookies and after getting data from cookies I am updating both datepicker (firstDatePicker, secondDatePicker) like this...

FIRST TRY

```
$("#firstDatePicker").data('datepicker').setDate(moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
$("#secondDatePicker").data('datepicker').setDate(moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
```

SECOND TRY

```
$("#firstDatePicker").datepicker('setDate',moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
$("#secondDatePicker").datepicker('setDate',moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
```

THIRD TRY

```
$("#firstDatePicker").datepicker('update',moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
$("#secondDatePicker").datepicker('update',moment(obj.date_and_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')._d);
```

above mentioned all try are working and I have also tried to get date from datepicker using ***$("#firstDatePicker").datepicker('getDate');***. I am getting the date also what I have set programmatically but **datepicker's view remain same as like nothing happened**.

I have used moment.js to convert the date from a JSON object that is 'obj' which is coming in dd-mm-yyyy format so please don't get confused here these all are working even I am able to see the console of *$('#firstDatePicker').on('changeDate')* but **the problem is with view which is not showing the date what is being set**.

https://jsfiddle.net/devqualwebs/5gvn5w1y/9/